# How to use prefix table names with jpa

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, persistence

I'm using java play to make a web application and I'm having some trouble persisting data using ebeans and jpa annotations.
I've searched a lot, and I'm a little confused, I think that this is something that should be common, I want to have tables named like this:

- company 1_users
- company 2_users
- company N_users

but I want to have only one entity named user, can be possible to have this schema ?

I've searched about using one entity with multiple tables, about using table name prefixes and about using dynamic table name but I got nothing helpful.

Some ideas ??

Comment: Why do you want to store your users in separate tables?  Why not have the company stored as a field/column of the user entity/table?

Comment: Because I don't want a user table that grows up to infinity, you say that I have a concept error ? Is it wrong prevent tables grow like that ?

Comment: If that is your only concern, then yes, it's wrong.  Your database will provide techniques to manage large tables.  First strategy is making a unique index on your company ID and user ID (in that order).  The second strategy (if the first one isn't enough) is to make a partition on the company.  Unless you have a billion users, I doubt you'll need to partition though.  The index should suffice for tens of millions

Answer (score 0):

As @GlennLane said in comment,  creating separate tables isn't good idea, instead use some field as a company id/discriminator. You will save tons of nerves, and you won't need to update your code each time when new company joins the branch.

If you really want separate tables create separate model for each company, at least you won't mishmash that in code.